# Is it safe not to close a Java Scanner, provided I close the underlying readable?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

If I have a method that takes a reader and I want to operate on the reader with a Scanner like so:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    //blah blah blah
}
```

Is it safe not to close `scanner`? Documentation says that it "closes this scanner" and then talks about closing the underlying readable. Suppose I don't want to close the readable and instead want the caller to close `reader` when ready. Is it safe not to close `scanner` here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It depends what you want to be safe against.

- If you are just trying to ensure that the underlying stream is closed, then either approach is fine.
- If you also want the `Scanner` to be marked as closed (so that all subsequent operations on the object will fail immediately), then you should call `Scanner.close()`.

This is a general principle; i.e. it also applies to various kinds of streams that do in-memory buffering, one way or another.

Comment: This answer matches the contract as defined in [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29).

Answer (score 11):

Since I already have the source code open :-) ...

The `close()` method checks to see if the underlying `Readable` also implements the `Closeable` interface, and if it does it closes it.  In your situation you are saying this is not a concern because it will be closed later.

But the `close()` method also sets some internal flags indicating that the `Scanner` (and underlying `Readable`) are closed.  Many of the public methods first check to see if the `Scanner` has been closed.  So the danger here would be that maybe your underlying `Readable` has been closed, but further calls to the `Scanner` don't immediately throw an `IllegalStateException`, and instead fail in some other way as they proceed.

If you can ensure that nothing else has a handle to the `Scanner` instance in question, and won't try to call any further methods on it, then you may be ok.

The `close()` method also nulls out its reference to the `Readable`, so if this doesn't happen the `Scanner` wouldn't get garbage collected as soon as it would have had you called `close()`.

I'd call `Scanner.close()` if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to close the `Scanner` as well, and keep the underlying stream open for further work. What I did is create a class that extends `BufferedInputStream` and overrides the `close()` method with an empty body. This class I fed into the constructor of the `Scanner`. This way, you can call `scanner.close()` without closing the stream. You need to keep a reference to the original `BufferedInputStream` though, but that is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have Caller and Reader class. Caller shouldn't know about the implementation of Reader. In reader's next method:

```
while scanner has object
   read them ( one object per method's call) 
when objects are done
   close the reader.
```

This is a kind of iterator pattern.