# Close a Scanner linked to System.in

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a `Scanner` linked to `System.in`. Now, after using the `Scanner`, I should close it, as it is bad coding practice to leave it open. But, if I close the `Scanner`, I will also be closing `System.in`! Can anyone tell me how I can close the `Scanner` without closing `System.in` (if there is any way).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919143/is-it-safe-not-to-close-a-java-scanner-provided-i-close-the-underlying-readable hopefully this can be of use to you. Im still looking to see if System.in implements closeable. If not, they you're in the clear.

Comment: Note that you can guard the stream with a [decorator](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html).

Comment: Yep, System.in does implement closeable.

Comment: @pauljerman `System.in` is a `InputStream` and therefore implements `AutoClosable`, see [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).

Comment: scratch that, don't close you're scanner. I'll post the answer

Comment: @McDowell sorry about hijacking your answer. Didn't see it until I had already posted the same thing XD

Comment: @pauljerman - not an issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing BufferedReader and System.in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203981/closing-bufferedreader-and-system-in)

Comment: *"Doctor, it hurts when I do this!" ... "Don't do that, then."*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One option is to wrap your `System.in` stream in a `CloseShieldInputStream` that prevents it from being closed. Your reader would then use the `CloseShieldInputStream` rather than the raw `System.in` stream.

Here is the API for the class:
http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html

Comment: you could also create your own custom un-closeable wrapper for the System.in stream

Answer (score 32):

The simplest thing is to not close Scanner if you don't want to close the underlying stream.

Ideally you should create just one Scanner which you use for the life of the program.  In any case, it appears you don't have a good reason to close it.

Comment: This works by requiring code to KNOW it's talking to system in, or at least something that shouldn't be closed.  Paul Jermans recommendation of `CloseShieldInputStream` allows the code to ignore that fact and simply treat it like any other InputStream and attempt to close it when finished.  What is simple here really depends on context.

Comment: @candied_orange you shouldn't be closing a stream that you don't own (which, given the lack of a strong notion of ownership in Java, roughly means that you didn't *open*). If you got the stream from somewhere else, don't close the Scanner.

Comment: @AndyTurner that works. If you want to follow that rule and still have freedom to use widely look up the [hole in the middle pattern](https://www.google.com/amp/s/jbergmanster.wordpress.com/2007/09/12/a-simple-example-of-the-hole-in-the-middle-pattern/amp/)

Answer (score 10):

Instead of adding shield classes and stuff like that, just put a nice comment and a

```
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
```

That's good enough. And I don't seem to see a lot of drawbacks to this approach. Don't forget the comment.

Comment: ? This might supress a warning but doesn't prevent you from getting an `IOException: Stream closed` when trying to use the `System.in` after closing the Scanner

Comment: @derHugo I think they mean **don't** close the Scanner and suppress the warnings about *that* with an annotation and add an explaining comment.

Answer (score -1):

I have vague memories of strange, undiagnosable problems long ago with using the same `Scanner` of `System.in` twice, so this is what I use (even though you should probably just use one scanner for the duration of the program):

```
static String input() {
    try {
        return new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

For some reason this works without warnings, whereas if I don't do the catch-throw, Eclipse will complain `Resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' is never closed`.

Comment: You're just avoiding the warning by confusing Eclipse code analysis here :)  The scanner is still never closed (not that you should :))

Answer (score -12):

According to the [API for InputSteam](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#close--) "The close method of InputStream does nothing.", so since System.in is an instance of InputStream, you don't need to worry about close() being called on it.

Comment: Clearly that's not the case though. If I open a `Scanner` on `System.in`, close it, and then open another and then try to use it (e.g. `nextLine()`), I get `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: While `close()` indeed does nothing in the default implementation of the abstract `InputStream`, that doesn't mean this is true for all of its subclasses! If that was true, the method would be useless.

Comment: `InputStream` is an abstract class. Subclasses can and should "do something" when they represent a resource (such as stdin) that needs to be closed after use. Granted that could be made clearer in `InputStream.close()`, but your conclusion is incorrect.

Comment: This answer is totally wrong, and I think it need to be deleted

Comment: If we see the other methods of InputStream, like [mark](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#mark-int-), it also said _The mark method of InputStream does nothing._ But if we see the the [reset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset--) method, it said _The method reset for class InputStream does nothing except throw an IOException._ So the sentence above about _does nothing_ referring to e.g. throwing an Exception