# what is the purpose of closing the scanner in java?

Tags: java

I had a line of code

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
```

and I use input to get some user input.

My program warns me that there is a resource leak because input is never closed.

Once I add the line

```
input.close();
```

it stops complaining and everything works fine.

I am new to Java and was wondering what is the purpose of closing input?  what does it do.

Comment: Note: in this case it's not necessarily a good idea, because `input.close()` also calls `System.in.close`. If you're working with files, or sockets, or anything else, then you do want to close them, hence the warning.

Comment: Closing resources is a good practice to avoid leaks. However, for the usage in this question, you should also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142853/close-a-scanner-linked-to-system-in as your `Scanner` is tied to `System.in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prevents memory leaks. When `Scanner`s (or any other File I/O classes) are closed, their resources are released and memory is freed.

Comment: It's also smart and courteous resource management.