# Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) - Resource Leak?

Tags: java

Here is the code I'm messing around with:

```
import java.util.*; public class Work {

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Type 1 to convert from Farenheit to Celsius. Type 2 to convert from Farenheit to Kelvin.");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double x = sc.nextDouble();
    while ((x != 1) && (x != 2)){
    System.out.println("Please enter a value of either 1 or 2");
    x = sc.nextDouble();
    }

    if (x == 1){
        System.out.println("Enter the degrees in F and it will be converted to C:");
        double y = sc.nextDouble();
        double ans = convertoC(y);
        System.out.println(ans + " C");
    } else if (x == 2){
        System.out.println("Enter the degrees in F and it will be converted to K:");
        double v = sc.nextDouble();
        double ans = convertoK(v);
        System.out.println(ans + " K");
    } 
}


public static double convertoK(double x){
    return ((x + 459.67) * (5.0/9.0));
}

public static double convertoC(double x){
    return ((x - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0));
}
```

}

Eclipse tells me there is a resource leak for the Scanner. How can I correct this?
Also, is there a more efficient way to receive inputs then this? I feel like my implementation is very blocky and re-uses the same code over an over. Also, would I use a try/catch to allow a user to re-enter another input if they don't input a number (as it is, an exception simply gets thrown).

Thanks!

Comment: Please share relevant parts of the code here, don't link us to places.

Comment: Don't create more than one `Scanner`. Create one, and only one, then use it wherever needed. Lifetime is entire `main()` method, so in the end, one resource may be detected as being leaked, which is not really true, so just ignore that, because you don't want to close the underlying `System.in`.

Comment: I have updated the code from a link. Sorry!

Comment: This question & answer could be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14143047/638028

Answer (score 2):

You need to [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()) the scanner so that any resources held by it can be released. Ideally, this is done in a finally block so that you are sure that you will always release the resources accumulated by the scanner.

Thus, you would need to declare the scanner: `Scanner sc = null`, then, wrap the remainder of your method within a try-catch block. Lastly, add a `finally` block wherein you close the scanner (`sc`) provided that it is not null.

As per @Kevin Esche comment, you can also use the [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which is similar to C#'s `using` directive.

You are also declaring multiple scanners on the same item within the same scope. The scanner you declare at the top should be enough, `sx` and `sy` are unneeded.

Comment: I removed all of the additional scanners. Where would I place the close(); statement?

Comment: You could also use the `try with ressources`.

Comment: @KevinEsche: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov: You are not closing `System.in`, you are closing a handle to it which your application no longer needs.

Comment: @npinti closing a Scanner also causes the underlying stream to be closed. So in this case, by closing the Scanner you are also closing System.in.