# I can't see why my scanner in java is throwing a "NoSuchElementException"

Tags: java

We need to make something of a lexical analyzer, and I have had some trouble with a particular function of mine, useLoad, or more accurately, what happens in Main after useLoad is used.

I figured out that that was because...for some reason, `buffer=keyboard.nextLine()` is throwing the error, because it's not getting more input from the keyboard for some reason. I thought that .nextLine() should force it to get more input from the user. And I don't know why it's throwing that exception specifically after this one particular method. It can do other methods just fine and not lose its ability to read. Is it because I have a variable called keyboard in another object and closed it? That seems doubtful. Just tried changing the name. Didn't make a difference.

Variables used but not declared in the below code: Keywords[0] is the String "load ". initial = the scanner string that's passed in to the function. offset = a counter variable, to see how far in to the line we've read.

The useLoad function (which is what I think is messing up somehow), is at the bottom, but I included everything it runs through (with each method separated by a horizontal rule), in chronological order, just in case I'm just not seeing what's going on.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //the scanner for keyboard
        int i = 0;
        String buffer ="";
        boolean loopControl == true;
        SymbolTable mySym = new SymbolTable();

        System.out.println("READY FOR INPUT\n");

        while (loopControl == true){
            //read in the line
            buffer = "";
            buffer = keyboard.nextLine();
            if(!mySym.checkStop(buffer)){ //if we didn't stop
                mySym.primary(buffer);
            }
            else{//if we did stop
                closeLoop();
            }

            if (i >= 55){
                loopControl = false;
                System.out.println(("You have gone over the limit ("+i+" lines) per execution. Please continue by running this program again.").toUpperCase());
                //just a safety precaution...you know... in case closeLoop doesn't work
            }
            i++;
        }


        keyboard.close();

    }
```

---

```
    if(initial.substring(0, Keywords[0].length()).equals(Keywords[0])){ //Load
        //if this is working as expected, then we simply need to do what the keyword says to do.
        offset += Keywords[0].length(); //we have moved this much deeper in to the line
        useLoad(offset, initial);
        offset = 0; //just make sure, once we are done with the line, we start back at the start of the next line.
        return; //we found what we were looking for, get out.
    }
```

---

```
private void useLoad(int offsetIn, String readIn) {
        double doubIn = 0;
        //now get the value of the 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //the scanner for keyboard
            System.out.println("\nENTER VALUE FOR " + readIn.toUpperCase());
             doubIn = keyboard.nextDouble();    
        keyboard.close();

        variables.create(readIn.substring(offsetIn), doubIn);
    }
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the 'loopControl'?

Comment: `keyboard.close();` closes the keyboard (duh) so you can't type or read anything. (Actually that's not *quite* correct, but close enough)

Comment: @beatrice It was a global variable in main's class (so that other methods could mess with it, like closeLoop() ). That was why it wasn't copied. I forgot about that. I added it back in as a local variable, since it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: @immibis Thanks. That was from when I used ctrl+z 1 fewer times than I thought I did. I fixed that, and am still getting the same error

Comment: Stop calling keyboard.close().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out your problem.

Java docs for both Java 7 and 8 include this line in Scanner's close method documentation:

> If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying readable also implements the `Closeable` interface then the readable's `close` method will be invoked.

Looking into the docs for System, I've found that System.in is of type `InputStream` which, you guessed it, implements `Closeable`. The `close` method documentation for `InputStream` says that it does nothing; however, `InputStream` is `abstract` and `close` is *not* marked as `final`, which means it can be overridden. `System.in` returns an `InputStream` which could potentially - and clearly *does* - do something.

So the problem is, you are creating multiple `Scanner`s with `System.in`, and each time you close *any one of them*, you close `System.in`, rendering it useless!

This problem has actually been discussed in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142853/close-a-scanner-linked-to-system-in), with a solution given. That said, for your program I would suggest one of two approaches:

- The first approach is mentioned there: Either use a pre-made wrapper class or make your own, which accepts an `InputStream` in its constructor. Have this class' `InputStream` implementation call all the methods of its wrapped object, except for the `close` method which is a no-sell, and then pass `Wrapper(System.in)` to Scanner instead of `System.in` directly. However, I would be wary of taking this approach except in very specific circumstances, because any time you use one of these wrappers you would need to remember to `close` its wrapped object at the end of its use, unless it's something like `System.in`.
- Second approach: Use a runner class in your program, and initialize the scanner there. Pass the scanner into the required objects during construction for them to hold a reference to, and then allow them to complete their required tasks *without closing Scanner within the class*. Once the exit condition is specified, return to the runner class and `close` Scanner from there.

Comment: To be fair, @immibis actually said this before me, but it wasn't very clearly stated due to the fact that your input reader is actually named `keyboard`. They were trying to say what I'm saying now - that calling a `System.in` Scanner's `close` method "closes" the keyboard itself

Comment: I am thinking you might be right.. I had similar suspicions. Working on my Lisp program is giving me a headache. I'll try implementing what you said in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

You close the `keyboard` each time round the loop. Therefore the second time around you read from a closed `keyboard` object.

A quick look at the **documentation** for `Scanner.nextLine` contains the news that it might throw:

```
NoSuchElementException - if no line was found
```

Comment: Oops, sorry. That was from when I used ctrl+z 1 fewer times than I thought I did. I fixed that, and am still getting the same error.

Comment: You probably should call hasNextLine before calling nextLine.  I'm not particularly familiar with Scanner, but generally Java methods follow a haveNext/next pattern.  The doc for hasNextLine says it may block for input, for nextLine it says no such thing.

Comment: hmm? I thought that nextLine and likewise nextDouble had it read in from the keyboard (or however the scanner was initialized). I'll try that.

Comment: OK! I'll update my question. Turns out that the problem is, in fact, with the main method. Found out when I tried doing what you suggested, and (because it had no line after the the loop, I guess), it tried to pass in an empty string to mySym.checkStop().