# Java scanner frustrations

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I have the following method:

```
private String doEntryScan(InputStream stream)
{
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stream)) // Reading from System.in
    {
        String readString = scanner.nextLine();
        if (readString.isEmpty())
        {
            readString = "\n";
        }
        scanner.nextLine(); //consume carriage returns if they remain
        scanner.close();
        return readString;
    }
}
```

The idea is that the user can hit enter to accept defaults. Or they can enter something. If I include the line

```
scanner.nextLine(); //consume carriage returns if they remain
```

the method hangs at that point, presumably waiting for more input. If I don't have that line, I get a NoSuchElementException the next time I call this method. I'm assuming this is because there's a carriage return in the stream.

So how does one get around this? scanner.hasNext() doesn't help because it ALSO "sometimes" blocks.
By the way, in practice InputStream is System.in.

Comment: Don't close System.in

Comment: I'm not closing System.in

Comment: The try-with-resources **closes** `System.in` **and** so does `scanner.close();` So you are closing it *twice*.

Comment: You are.  When you close a scanner pointing at System.in, you are also closing the stream. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142853/close-a-scanner-linked-to-system-in

Comment: ensure you have enough to consume with method like `if (scanner.hashNextLine())` before consuming from input source and remove close call on your scanner.

Comment: oh goddamit java. just when I expect you to be reasonable.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: this was indeed the cause. Elliot or azurefrog, if you want to write an answer I'll accept it.