# Issue with Scanner and loops

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, system.in

I've been reading about issues with Scanner, but even after adding in an extra `in.nextLine()` or `in.nextInt()` all Java does is move the `NoSuchElementException` up to that line. Any suggestions? I'm trying to create an auto-looping menu selection for my program. Every time it loops case 1, it has an issue.

```
while (!done) {
 System.out.println("Welcome, please type a number for selecting from the following: \n 1. Insert Process \n 2. Print out a list of processes \n 3. See and remove first priority process \n 4. Quit");

 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 int selector = 0;
 print(); in .nextLine();
 selector = in .nextInt();

 switch (selector) {
  case 1:
   System.out.println("Please enter a priority for the new process > 0");
   Scanner pin = new Scanner(System.in);
   priority = pin.nextInt();
   if (priority > 0) {
    maxHeapInsert(priority); //allows user to set priority
    in .close(); in = new Scanner(System.in);
    break;

   } else {
    System.out.println("ERROR, you did not enter a number greater than 0");
   }
   break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use scanner's [hasNextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()) and it's other variants before trying to get the token with next*.

There is no necessity to use multiple scanners for `System.in`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

Note that there is no need to use/declare multiple scanners. Also try to avoid declaring variables inside loops as it is not efficient(memory/performance).

```
boolean done = false;
    int priority = 0, selector = 0;
    try(Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in))
    {
        while (!done ) {
            System.out.println("Welcome, please type a number for selecting from the following: \n 1. Insert Process \n 2. Print out a list of processes \n 3. See and remove first priority process \n 4. Quit");
            selector = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();

            switch(selector){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Please enter a priority for the new process > 0");
                priority = in.nextInt();
                in.nextLine();

                if (priority > 0) {
                    maxHeapInsert(priority);//allows user to set priority
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ERROR, you did not enter a number greater than 0");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that the try with resource statement will also close `System.in` and not just the scanner. If you want to use `System.in` outside the try block, either don't use try with resource or [shield it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14143048/8089107)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting that same error at selector = in.nextInt();

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
while (!done) {
        System.out.println(
                "Welcome, please type a number for selecting from the following: \n 1. Insert Process \n 2. Print out a list of processes \n 3. See and remove first priority process \n 4. Quit");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int selector = 0;
        selector = in.nextInt();

        switch (selector) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Please enter a priority for the new process > 0");
            Scanner pin = new Scanner(System.in);
            priority = pin.nextInt();
            if (priority > 0) {
                maxHeapInsert(priority); //allows user to set priority
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR, you did not enter a number greater than 0");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

The reason is that when you use `in.close()` it will also close the `System.in` so you will read -1 and throw the exception. Remember a program cannot reopen the `System.in` after closing it.