# Scanner.close method closes all scanners why?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In my code I opened two scanner methods but closing one scanner closes all`

```
class x{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        void print(){
        Scanner xd = new Scanner (System.in);
         xd.close()
     }
}
```

`here xd.close closes my scanner s too why so? and how can it overcome this? friends I need to know why?. And is there any other way to temporarily close my scanner to prevent memory leakage?

Comment: Because it closes the underlying input stream, which is unique across all your scanners. Don't close it

Comment: Do not use it then?

Comment: Also see this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142853/close-a-scanner-linked-to-system-in

Comment: Only close resources you have opened yourself. `System.in` is managed by the JVM, you don't need to close it. The JVM will close it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why?  Because that is how the specification says it should behave; see @Sun's answer for the reference and the text from the spec.

> And how can it overcome this?

Don't call `close()` in a `Scanner` that wraps `System.in`.  This is just an application of the general principle that a resource should be closed by the same code that opens it.  (The JVM opens `System.in` so you shouldn't close it.)

Alternatively if you *must* close the `Scanner`, write or find a `InputStream` wrapper class that ignores the `close()` method and then use that to wrap `System.in`.

By the way, it is a bad idea to instantiate `new Scanner(System.in)` more than once.  The problem is that a `Scanner` may read any or all type-ahead.  If you have two or more of them wrapping the same underlying stream, one `Scanner` can capture input that a later one needs to read.  This can lead to occasional unexpected behavior, and is likely to cause your application to fail if standard input is redirected ... at the shell level.

Answer (score 3):

Because [`Scanner.close`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()) will close `System.in` implicitly:

> If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying
>   readable also implements the Closeable interface then the readable's
>   close method will be invoked.