# Java Monopoly player select validation

Tags: java

I am programming a monopoly type game on java and am having a little trouble setting up the validation for the player select function. The user will have to chose between 2-4 players.

Below is my attempt at doing this utilizing an if else statement and a while loop.

I can't figure out the right way of implementing this and would appreciate any advice.

```
int numberPlayers = 0;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter Number of players (2-4)");

if (scanner.nextInt() >= 2 && scanner.nextInt() <= 4) {
    numberPlayers = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(numberPlayers + " players selected");
} else {
    while (scanner.nextInt() < 2 || scanner.nextInt() > 4) {
        System.out.println("Not a valid choice. Please enter Number of players (2-4)");
    }
}
```

Comment: I see your code making three calls to the scanner to retrieve an integer input, when you probably should only be making one call.

Comment: Yikes, you are throwing out the user's input with that while loop condition as this: `while (scanner.nextInt() < 2 || scanner.nextInt() > 4)` gets the user's input and completely discards it since the input is not put into a variable. Get the user's input into a variable *within* the while loop, not the while loop's condition. Check the state of this variable within the condition.

Comment: Every time you say scanner.nextInt() your program looks for a user input instead call it once and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `do-while` loop to ask the user at least once for the player count and keep asking until the input is valid.

```
public int askForPlayers(Scanner scanner) {
    int numberPlayers = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter Number of players (2-4)");
        numberPlayers = scanner.nextInt();
    } while(numberPlayers < 2 || numberPlayers > 4);
    return numberPlayers;
}
```

When you use a `Scanner` object, keep in mind that the user might enter something else that is not a number. You have to work with `hasNextInt()` and `next()` to deal with such a situation. Also, when you close the `Scanner` object, you are also closing the `InputStream` you used, see [Close a Scanner linked to System.in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142853/close-a-scanner-linked-to-system-in).