# How to close Scanner opened in a method JAVA

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I started learning JAVA a couple of days ago, so my question might be too basic.

I have created a piece of code which is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Que01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int principle=acceptInt("Principle");
        int roi=acceptInt("Rate Of Interest");
        int years=acceptInt("Years");
        float si=simpleInterest(principle,roi,years);

        System.out.println("Simple Interest for given details is : "+si);
    }

    static int acceptInt(String s1)
    {   System.out.println("Please Enter value for "+s1+" :");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i= sc.nextInt();
        return i;
    }
    static float simpleInterest(int p,int r, int yr)
    {
        return p*yr*r/100;
    }

}
```

I want to know where should I write:

> sc.close();

Also:

> Any other suggestion to code for improvement are Welcome!

Comment: The title suggests there is a loop, but I don't see any.

Comment: You are creating a new `Scanner` each time you call `acceptInt`. Don't create a new `Scanner` each time, reuse the same one.

Comment: You should never close `System.in`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14142853/1553851

Comment: @VinceEmigh, where should I create the scanner? If I create it in main function then I am unable to use it. Please could you write a better code version for me?

Comment: @theSwapnilSaste You could create the `Scanner` in `main` and pass it as an argument to `acceptInt`. Or you could create a static field variable. What you should *really* do is define a type, maybe `InputAcceptor`, which will own the `Scanner`. The `InputAcceptor` could then define the `acceptInt`. You'd instantiate an `InputAcceptor` in main & tell it to `acceptInt` (call the method).

Comment: @VinceEmigh, I got your first Approach of passing `Scanner` as an argument, but I am not getting the rest approaches, would you please elaborate with a code? I am a newbie.

Comment: You shouldn't close the `Scanner` at all. It's just a class, not a resource. The resource is `System.in` and closing the `Scanner` will also close the resource. It's suppose to be closed by the `JVM` when the program exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Vince, I was able to create a good version of my code.
and this is the answer I needed.

````
public class Que01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int principle=acceptInt(sc,"Principle");
        int roi=acceptInt(sc,"Rate Of Interest");
        int years=acceptInt(sc,"Years");
        sc.close();
        float si=simpleInterest(principle,roi,years);

        System.out.println("Simple Interest for given details is : "+si);
    }

    static int acceptInt(Scanner sc,String s1)
    {   System.out.println("Please Enter value for "+s1+" :");

        int i= sc.nextInt();
        return i;
    }
    static float simpleInterest(int p,int r, int yr)
    {
        return p*yr*r/100;
    }

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Que01 {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int principle = acceptInt("Principle");
        int roi = acceptInt("Rate Of Interest");
        int years = acceptInt("Years");
        float si = (p * yr * r/100);

        System.out.println("Simple Interest for given details is : " + si);
    }

    static int acceptInt(String s1) {   
        System.out.println("Please Enter value for " + s1 + " :");

        int i = sc.nextInt();

        sc.close();

        return i;
    }
}
```

This is what I would say but I'm not an expert. `sc.close` just saves anything you did with the scanner, eg. writing to a file and saving the file. - thus in this scenario I wouldn't even use it.  I also wouldn't use a method to `calc` the `si` unless you plan to use it elsewhere as it's just taking up more space

Comment: It throws errors:---Please Enter value for Principle :
1000
Please Enter value for Rate Of Interest :
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
 at Assignments.Que01.acceptInt(Que01.java:20)
 at Assignments.Que01.main(Que01.java:9)

Comment: retry, had to format a few things
EDIT: looks like you have a lot more uses of scanner - thus I wouldn't close it until you're 100% done with it, if you need to close it at all that is

Comment: You are putting the scanner above the class. It should be inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Que01 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int principle = acceptInt("Principle", false, sc);
    int roi = acceptInt("Rate Of Interest", false, sc)
    int years = acceptInt("Years", true, sc);
    float si = simpleInterest(principle, roi, years);

    System.out.println("Simple Interest for given details is : " + si);
}


static int acceptInt(String s1, boolean closeScanner, Scanner sc) {
    System.out.println("Please Enter value for " + s1 + " :");

    int i = sc.nextInt();
    if (closeScanner)
        sc.close();
    return i;
}
static float simpleInterest(int p, int r, int yr) {
    return p * yr * r / 100;
}
```

}

i am not sure if this is a good practice of passing boolean as parameter to decide to close scanner

Comment: Yes, it works but my Question is without to close scanner discarding acceptInt() method

Answer (score 0):

You should not close the scanner do not worry about that it will terminated after calculating the `simpleInterest`. When you run the program and after entering required values it will calculate and return the result and quit.
In you code 1 improvement is you should not create `Scanner` object again and again there should be only 1 object of `Scanner` throughout the life cycle.

Below is your updated code -

```
public class Que01 {
private static Scanner sc = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int principle=acceptInt("Principle");
    int roi=acceptInt("Rate Of Interest");
    int years=acceptInt("Years");
    float si=simpleInterest(principle,roi,years);

    System.out.println("Simple Interest for given details is : "+si);
}

static int acceptInt(String s1)
{   System.out.println("Please Enter value for "+s1+" :");

    int i= sc.nextInt();
    return i;
}
static float simpleInterest(int p,int r, int yr)
{
    return p*yr*r/100;
}

}
```

Create `Scanner` on start of the program and use it again and again. thats it

hope this will help you.