# Exception in thread "main" no line found. java

Tags: java, methods, user-input

I'm trying to write a code that checks your gender and the .length of your name.
I'm getting an error that reads:
"Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found."
...I need some help with the syntax, thank you.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

public class nameEvaluator {
String gender = maleOrFemale();
int nameLength = lengthOfName();

public String maleOrFemale () {
        Scanner maleorfemale = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter gender, male or female:");
        String gender = maleorfemale.nextLine();
        maleorfemale.close();
        return gender;
}        

public void confirmUserInput1 () {
    if (gender.equals("male")||gender.equals("female")){
    System.out.println("Thank you...");} else {System.out.println("Please, write male or female:");}    
    }

public int lengthOfName() {
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name, please:");
        String yourname = name.nextLine();
        name.close();
        return yourname.length();
}

 public static void main (String[]args) {
     nameEvaluator user = new nameEvaluator();
 }}
```

Comment: please understand the difference between scanner.next() and scanner.nextLine() methods.. Also, class variables should generally not be assigned with function calls. Create a constructor to do it. That way you don't have to declare so many scanner variables..

Comment: You should not be continually creating new Scanner objects. Create one near the beginning of your program and make it either an instance variable or pass it to your functions.

Comment: When y o u close a scanner, it closes the underlying stream. So the next time you try to use a scanner, the stream is closed, so it thinks there is no input.

Comment: Have you seen this SO question: [Close a Scanner linked to System.in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142853/close-a-scanner-linked-to-system-in)