# InvocationTargetException while setting values in Java

Tags: java, invocationtargetexception

I have problem with InvocationTargetException.
I am setting values of object using scanner and it became to return such strange exception for me. I did read doc and i was searching internet to find solution, but I can't figure out what's wrong.
Also don't read println strings, they are in my native language.

```
public Person SignPerson() { 

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Tworzymy twoje konto użytkownika, podaj dane osobowe");
    System.out.println("Podaj swoj pesel");

    String id = setPersonalId();
    Person person = new Person(id);
    System.out.println("Podaj swoje imie");
    person.setFirstName(scanner.nextLine()); // the line taht causes problem (other 
                                                // scanners also throws exceptions)
    System.out.println("Podaj drugie imie");
    //tutaj powinien byc wgrany drugi kod do odczytu imienia
    System.out.println("Podaj nazwisko");
    person.setLastName(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Podaj nazwisko panienskie matki");
    person.setMotherMaidensName(scanner.nextLine());

    return person;
}

public static String setPersonalId() {
    String id;
    try (
            Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    ) {
        id = scanner2.next();

        char[] chars = id.toCharArray();

        for (char aChar : chars) {
            if (!(aChar >= '0' && aChar <= '9'))
                throw new InvalidStringException();
        }

        return id;
    } catch (InvalidStringException e) {
        System.out.println("Wprowadziles niepoprawny pesel");
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the full exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be at least two issues here:

1. Don't close a `Scanner` wrapping `System.in`, as this will also
   close the underlying stream. (see
   [Close a Scanner linked to System.in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142853/close-a-scanner-linked-to-system-in))

   To fix this, remove the the creation of the second `Scanner` from
   the `try-with-resource` block, to avoid it getting closed
   automatically. You may also not create a second scanner, but pass
   the first one to the method where it will be used.

   ```
   String id = setPersonalId(scanner);
   ```

   and in your `setPersonalId`:

   ```
   public static String setPersonalId(Scanner s) { ...
   ```
2. Calling `nextLine()` after calling `next()` will also cause
   problems, explained here:
   [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo):

   To fix the second issue, you may simply call `nextLine()` everytime,
   instead of `next()` (or consume the linefeed as shown in the link):

   ```
   id = s.nextLine();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Print e.printStackTrace() inside of Exception e block and then it points to the actual stack trace in the JDK Library. Go inside of it in the library and figure out which line is throwing error and figure out the solution based on line number in JDK Library.

Comment: It shows something like : java.util.NoSuchElementException: no line found. The question is why there are no lines are being found?