# Why is scanner reading no input and exiting function?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've created a method that asks a user for their favorite number. When I call this function more than once in my main, all method calls thereafter will jump to closing and declare `Your favorite number is: 0` without asking for input. I'd like to know why a fresh scanner is reading and accepting no input.

```
    public static void favNumber(){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter you favorite number: ");
    int favNumber = 0;
    boolean hasNextInt = scanner.hasNextInt();

    if(hasNextInt){
        favNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine(); //reads enter character
    }

    System.out.println("Your favorite number is: " + favNumber);
    scanner.close();
    }
```

Comment: You are closing `stdin` - with `scanner.close();` - don't do that.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Please forgive my noobness, but why is 'scanner.close();' a bad way to close 'stdin'? And why would that be preventing a new scanner from asking for input?

Comment: You do not need to close `stdin` and if you do you can not re-open it.

Comment: However closing input streams is good practice so you shouldn't _not_ close the scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Scanner` instance wraps `System.in` (stdin). When you call `scanner.close()` at the end of your method, you're actually closing `System.in` in addition to your scanner. Once the input stream is closed, it can't be opened again.

The solution is, of course, to share a single instance of the Scanner. I note that you're using static methods, so I will similarly use a static instance in the following example. Note how I create the scanner, then I call `favNumber()`, and I only close the scanner after I finish calling `favNumber()`. This allows me to call `favNumber()` multiple times and share the same scanner instance.

```java
private static Scanner scanner; // note that this is a class-level static variable.
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // create the scanner
        favNumber(); // call the method
    } finally {
        scanner.close(); // only close the scanner when we're completely done
    }
}
public static void favNumber(){
    System.out.println("Enter you favorite number: ");
    int favNumber = 0;
    boolean hasNextInt = scanner.hasNextInt();

    if(hasNextInt){
        favNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine(); //reads enter character
    }

    System.out.println("Your favorite number is: " + favNumber);
}
```

An alternative solution would be to pass the scanner instance as a method parameter like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // create the scanner
    favNumber(scanner); // call the method, pass the scanner
    scanner.close(); // only close the scanner when we're completely done
}

public static void favNumber(Scanner scanner){
    System.out.println("Enter you favorite number: ");
    int favNumber = 0;
    boolean hasNextInt = scanner.hasNextInt();

    if(hasNextInt){
        favNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine(); //reads enter character
    }

    System.out.println("Your favorite number is: " + favNumber);
}
```

You can read more about closing scanners wrapping System.in in this Q&A here: [Close a Scanner linked to System.in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142853/close-a-scanner-linked-to-system-in)

Comment: thank you so much for your patience and explanation. This is the answer and I will mark it as soon as SO allows me to.