# NoSuchElementException with ArrayList inside Method

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I've got a class called "Player" that's supposed to

1. set a maximum player amount and
2. add player names to an ArrayList,

The class looks like this:

```
public class Player {

    private ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int maxPlayers = 0;


    public ArrayList<String> setPlayers(ArrayList<String> strArrList) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 1; i <= getMaxPlayers(); i++) {

            System.out.print("Player #" + i + ": ");
            String name = sc.next();
            strArrList.add(name);
            System.out.println();

        }

        return strArrList;
    }

    public void setMaxPlayers() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many players? ");
        maxPlayers = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        sc.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPlayers() {

        return players;
    }

    public int getMaxPlayers() {

        return maxPlayers;
    }
}
```

I call on the Player class methods from my Main class like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Player pl = new Player();

        pl.setMaxPlayers();
        pl.setPlayers(pl.getPlayers());
    }
}
```

But I get following output:

```
How many players? 2

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at com.arsaii.drinkgame.Player.setPlayers(Player.java:18)
    at com.arsaii.drinkgame.Main.main(Main.java:10)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I know what `NoSuchElementException` means (sort of..) But I've also tried using the same for-loop from the Player class in a different test class inside a main method and it worked.. Does that mean I am getting a `NoSuchElementException` because it's inside a method.. Could someone explain please..?

Comment: Try `sc.nextLine()` instead of `sc.next()`.

Comment: Don't close a `Scanner` wrapping `System.in`, it will close the underlying stream. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142853/close-a-scanner-linked-to-system-in.

Comment: @maloomeister wow that fixed everything.. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Thomas I tried that aswell before but I got the same error.. maloomeister's answer seems to fix it.

Comment: @maloomeister add your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted and others may benefit from it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is when calling `sc.close()` in your `setMaxPlayers()` method. This will close the underlying `System.in` input stream aswell.

Due to the fact that `System.in` has been closed and cannot be reopened, creating another `Scanner` wrapping `System.in` in your `setPlayers()` will fail.

So the simplest solution, as has also been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142853/close-a-scanner-linked-to-system-in), is to simply not close the `Scanner` instance, if it wraps `System.in`. Just use one shared `Scanner` instance and don't close it (at all, or at least if you know you will need it later).