# Scanner - java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

Does anyone see a problem with this? First input works fine, but after the first loop, it doesn't ask to enter a value again. How do I fix this?

```
    int value;
    while(true)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a value");
        try 
        {
            value = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("value provided is: " + value);
            scan.nextLine(); // consumes "\n" character in buffer
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e) // outputs error message if value provided is not an integer
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect input type. Try again.");
            continue; // restarts while loop to allow for re-entering of a valid input
        }
        scan.close();
    }
```

Comment: When will the loop actually stop?

Comment: That doesn't matter I can make it stop whenever but the main focus is the error

Comment: This is just an extraction from my actual code, I just set it as an infinite loop to investigate this particular cirumstance

Comment: Note I will be using the same scanner to read both integers and strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move `scan.close();` to outside the `while` loop.

Also you don't have to construct a *new* `Scanner` on each iteration. Move the declaration to outside the loop as well.

---

When [`close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29) the *Scanner*, this closes the [`System.in`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) input stream.

So now when you try to instantiate it again, it doesn't find any opened stream and you'll get that exception.

Comment: Are there cases where it's necessary to instantiate more than one scanner for a program?

Comment: What's wrong with my logic? I open and then close a scanner... at the next iteration this repeats. I don't see what's the problem with mine

Comment: Since [`close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()) closes the underlying stream, there will be nothing to read in the next iteration. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919143/is-it-safe-not-to-close-a-java-scanner-provided-i-close-the-underlying-readable) post.

Comment: But doesn't it gets opened back again? This line gets executed again on the next iteration -> Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: Why won't there be anything to read? My theory was that on the second iteration, it gets opened back and asks for value provided again. Why isn't this the case?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the while loop you have written `scan.close()`. This will close the scanner preventing any further scans. Removing that statement would ensure your while loop keeps asking you for the number(will be an infinite loop in your case)

Also, `scan.nextInt()` in effect ignores all new line and waits till you actually input a number and hit enter. So, `scan.nextLine()` can be omitted. You need that only in case where you use `scan.nextLine()` to fetch the value entered. In that case, the new line character is also read as an input, as a result of which you need an extra nextLine() call to consume it.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `scan.close()`, it closes the underlying `System.in` stream. So in the next iteration it will not have anything to read.

For example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int value;
        while (true) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a value");
            try {
                value = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println("value provided is: " + value);
                scan.nextLine(); // consumes "\n" character in buffer
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) // outputs error message if value
                                                // provided is not an integer
            {
                System.out.println("Incorrect input type. Try again.");
                continue; // restarts while loop to allow for re-entering of a
                            // valid input
            }
            scan.close();
            try {
                int x = System.in.read();
                System.out.println(x);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter a value
10
value provided is: 10
Enter a value
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:206)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at Main.main(Main.java:24)
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Check this question for more:

[Is it safe not to close a Java Scanner, provided I close the underlying readable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919143/is-it-safe-not-to-close-a-java-scanner-provided-i-close-the-underlying-readable)