# Where to close this `input` Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
package game1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class toothpicks {

    private int number;
    public int HowMany()
    {
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the No. of ToothPicks = ");
            Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
            number = input.nextInt(); 
            if(number<4)
            {
                System.out.print("ToothPicks Should be greater than 3\n");

            }

        }while(number<4);

        return number;
    }
}
```

Where can I close the `input` Scanner in my program? It giving me error if I close it in the end of the Program just before return statment says `input can not be resolved` but if I close it in the loop then I cannot achieve what i'm trying to by using this `HowMany` Method? What to do ? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `Scanner` on each loop. You don't need to, though, so you can just do

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
// do while loop goes here
```

And then close the Scanner just before the `return` statement.

Comment: Can u tell me why we ever wanna close the scanner?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919143/is-it-safe-not-to-close-a-java-scanner-provided-i-close-the-underlying-readable

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your `Scanner` out of the loop (look that you are creating a new instance of `Scanner` each time the loop make an iteration)

```
package game1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class toothpicks {

 private int number;
    public int HowMany()
    {
        Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);

        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the No. of ToothPicks = ");

            number = input.nextInt(); 
            if(number<4)
            {
                System.out.print("ToothPicks Should be greater than 3\n");

            }

        }while(number<4);

        input.close();

        return number;
    }
}
```

And then close it before the `return` statement.

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Answer (score 1):

Define and initialise `input` and `number` before the `do` loop, and close it immediately after the `do` loop.